# GRAPH API - Issues while accessing messages for the mail boxes; (MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI & ErrorInvalidUser)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am trying to read messages from two of my mail boxes using GRAPH APIs and getting following exceptions.

1. **ServiceException: Code: MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI
   Message: The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.**
   My mailbox is active (can access emails) and hosted on EXO only (can access emails using Microsoft GRAPH Explorer - login and providing consent explicitly).
   I have validated the generated accessToken and that is as per the configuration I did so it doesn't look like any issues with app registration.
2. **ServiceException: Code: ErrorInvalidUser
   Message: The requested user 'manoj.a.patel@outlook.com' is invalid.**
   This exception is with my another mailbox. This one is active I am able to access it.

Both of these email accounts I have created recently and shared the Office 365 family license I have. And added these two accounts to my Azure AD as users. These two accounts have all the required access so if I login to Azure account using these two accounts then I can see the app registered as well as other details thought it's not required.

I am suspecting these mailboxes are not associated properly with my Azure app id thought I have added them as AD users?

This request works and gives me 3 users with their email addresses

```
var client = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config);
var graphRequest = client.Users.Request();
var results = graphRequest.GetAsync().Result;
```

While accessing emails getting exceptions mentioned above. Below is the code

```
var inboxMessages = client.Users["manoj.a.patel@outlook.com"].
              MailFolders["inbox"].Messages.Request().Expand("attachments").Top(20).GetAsync();
            var response = inboxMessages.Result;
```

Please can you suggest what can be an issue here?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm afraid you can use `var inboxMessages = client.Users["user_principle_id"]` instead of `xx@outlook.com`.

Comment: you can use `client.Users["manoj.a.patel@outlook.com"].Request().GetAsync()` to get the user id. Your outlook account may have a user principle name like `manoj.a.patel@outlook.com#EXT#@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: @TinyWang, I tried with that it gives resource not found. seems something is missing with how my mailbox is connected to my Azure tenant. I have just added user but is that sufficient is a question.

Comment: `tried with that it gives resource not found` --> resource not found happened when you didn't assign an office license to that user. I'm not so sure about it, I can only say, I used to have a user in my tenant and at first it doesn't have an O365 license for it, so I met `no resource` issue, after I assign the license, it worked. Let's assume I had my account which already had a license which is assigned by my tenant, then you invite my account into your tenant, then can you query my mail messages via the azure ad app in your tenant? I think it's not a good idea....